# Translate known physical path into virtual path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to take files from a known location on disk and have ASP redirect to them from code-behind, allowing the browser/app/device to control how the content is displayed.

I tried using:

```
Server.Redirect(pathToFile);
```

But got the following exception: Invalid path for child request 'C:\ContentFolder\testImage.png'. A virtual path is expected.

How can I allow my site to redirect users to these files? I am storing the base directory in the web config, and the file names are stored in a database.

Comment: I have tried both answers in that question with the same exception.

Comment: Are the files stored outside your website directory?

Comment: Yes, they stored in an external, known, location on disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files reside outside of your website directory you can't redirect to them. Think about the security implications if that was possible. You have a few options

1. Move the files inside the website directory (or a sub-directory of it). Then you *can* redirect your users to them using a virtual path e.g. `Server.Redirect("~/files/somefile.zip")`.
2. Set up a virtual directory in IIS that maps to the physical location of the files on disk. Then you can redirect to them using the virtual path. You can [do this through the GUI or config file](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory).
3. Create a `HttpHandler` that loads the file from disk and returns them in the response. You can use a querystring to identify the file to load e.g. `/filehandler.ashx?filename=somefile.zip`. A quick google revealed [this example](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/asp-net/how-to-download-files-from-server-to-client-using-a-generic-handler/).

Comment: I ended up using the virtual directory, thanks for the answer!